# How do I set the `SameSite` attribute of HTTP cookies in python?

Tags: python, http, cookies

[Support for Same-Site cookies has landed in Firefox 60](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/04/24/same-site-cookies-in-firefox-60/), but as of Python 3.6 the standard library cookie module doesn't support the `SameSite` attribute.

Answer (score 10):

Support for the `SameSite` attribute was added on April 7, 2018 in [Pull Request #6413](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/6413).

It's possible to monkey-patch older versions to support the attribute:

```
try:
    from http.cookies import Morsel
except ImportError:
    from Cookie import Morsel

Morsel._reserved[str('samesite')] = str('SameSite')
```

Or using [six](http://six.readthedocs.io/):

```
from six.moves.http_cookies import Morsel

Morsel._reserved[str('samesite')] = str('SameSite')
```

Comment: why the `str` around `samesite` and `SameSite`?

Comment: To ensure compatibility with python 2 when the `unicode_literals` mode is on.

Comment: appreciate the clarification; this helped and since i use python 3 i removed the `str`