# Can't set SameSite attribute of cookie in Tornado

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

I'm trying to set a cookie with the `SameSite` header in a Tornado handler. I already looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50813092) and used the following monkeypatch:

```py
from http.cookies import Morsel
Morsel._reserved["samesite"] = "SameSite"
```

Then, in a different file which imports the monkeypatch above, I'm trying to do the following in a handler class that extends `RequestHandler`:

```py
from tornado.web import RequestHandler

class UserHandler(RequestHandler):
    async def login(self):
        # Application logic....
        self.set_secure_cookie("session_id", session_key, samesite: "None")
```

However, for some reason this doesn't work, and instead I'm getting an "invalid syntax" error.

Note that I'm using Python 3.7.4 and `tornado` v6.0.3.

Comment: `samesite: "None"` is not the way to pass kwargs, you should use `=` - `samesite="None"`

Comment: @IainShelvington My bad, thanks! Feel free to submit an answer, and I'll approve and upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`samesite: "None"` is not the way to pass keyword arguments to functions. You should use `=`

```
self.set_secure_cookie("session_id", session_key, samesite="None")
```